# Getting Value Error while adding days to a particular date

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using Python to add 2 days to a particular date in Python. Using `datetime.now()`, I'm able to add 2 days. But not using a particular date. Here's the code:

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('7/18/2016','%m/%d/%y')
date_to_start_predicting = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=2)   # Add 2 days
print(date_to_start_predicting)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Projects/DateAdd.py", line 3, in <module>
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('7/18/2016','%m/%d/%y')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 16
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing the string `'7/18/2016'` with the format `'%m/%d/%y'`.

`%y` tries to parse the year part in 2 digits format (so the year of your date object is 1920). So `2016` becomes `20` and `16` is left over which is what the error says.

You should be using `%Y` (which parses the year in 4 digits format) instead of `%y`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('7/18/2016','%m/%d/%Y')
```

(I've changed the lowercase `y` to an uppercase `Y`.)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the "adding" part. You just use the wrong formating.

You should change it to:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('7/18/2016','%m/%d/%Y')
```

as you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

I changed `y` to `Y`, since you use 4 digits year.